# Power Bi Create new Queries Automatically

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Wondering if there is anyway to create new queries for each item in this list of csv files from a folder import. I know that the folder import is used for combing multiple files into one table, was wondering if there was anyway to turn each CSV in this into it's own query.
[File source list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RytSC.png)

I've tried right clicking each of the column headers but this brings up the combine file option, I was hoping to be able to write a little code that would break these out into new queries for each CSV. However I am not well versed in M code or whatever language power query uses. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want separate queries for each file? That just seems a very odd thing to do since your code no longer works when files get added or removed.  Maybe instead share what the file contents look like and what the desired end state is

Comment: Hi Horseyride, Files wont be added or removed from the source folder theres just alot of them and I don't feel like making a query for each file in the screenshot above. They all contain different information that doesn't relate to any of the other files.